# Can we have clarity on legal questions being off topic in the help center?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, help-center

[Can I use the code in a GitHub project which does not have a license specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521080/can-i-use-the-code-in-a-github-project-which-does-not-have-a-license-specified)

This question was closed as off topic, but having read the off topic guide, I can't figure out why.

It seems to me that github clearly falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers" and the question regards "and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

It doesn't seem to match any of the other 6 reasons.

The best I can figure is that answering this question constitutes some sort of legal advice and that isn't a fitting topic for stackoverflow. If this is the reason, and it is considered legitimate, then it should be added as a 7th item in the list of reasons on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow deals with programming questions, literally the act of writing code and the IDEs we use, not the associated issues around it.

It is not practical to cite every use case that is not on topic. Instead focus on what is on topic. If something doesn't fall into the default close reasons, a custom close reason can be created when voting to close a post.

> ### [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

---

I've updated the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to add the following points:

> 7. Questions asking for support for offsite resources such as App Stores. Direct your questions to the relevant organisation instead.
> 8. Legal questions about copyright or licensing. [Open Source Stack
>    Exchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) or [Law Stack
>    Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) may be suitable.

Answer (score 6):

This is a legal question.  Supposing that the owner of that GitHub repository decided to litigate against entities which used that code, it would require an answer from qualified legal experts and a legal team.

We're not lawyers.  Trusting legal advice from the Internet is like using WebMD to diagnose a disease.  No one here can validate or vet each other's qualifications to answer a question like this.

Comment: I would hope that programmers do have some knowledge about what they can and can't use on github and for what. That doesn't mean you don't need to talk to a lawyer at some point, but it does mean that spreading general knowledge about what can and can't be done isn't valuable.

Comment: @Omn not if the only way to determine the correctness of that answer is by consulting a lawyer or going to court. Everything else is just supposition.

Comment: @muru That is absolutely not the only way to determine the correctness of the answer. There is a point where you need to talk to a lawyer, but there is clearly  value in disseminating general legal knowledge to people before they reach that point. Sources can be cited and while we are not absolute authorities, we as software engineers should know enough to recognize wildly inaccurate or misleading answers about basic licensing questions. See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276144/using-unlicensed-code

Comment: @Omn is that answer correct in all countries? Who has verified that correctness, and how did they verify it?

Comment: @Omn come to think of it, [software licensing *might* be on-topic on Software Engineering, or... dunno (the consensus isn't really clear)](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8284). But it's certainly off-topic on SO because it's not about practical programming.